# Move boot SSD from BIOS motherboard to UEFI motherboard?

Tags: boot, 18.04, uefi, bios

I'm (still) running 18.04 on a old BIOS-based motherboard.

Back in the day when all motherboards were BIOS-based, upgrading was as simple as moving a HDD from one system to another.  Is it still that simple when doing a to-UEFI migration?  (The current boot process *probably* uses UUID, but I'm not sure; computer just died: after 6-7 seconds, it powers back down.)

Comment: It'll depend if your system was installed with ESP & the ESP was written on that drive & correctly. For recent releases; some ISOs do not (*by default*) write ESP when BIOS machine is detected (*as it isn't required*) whilst others always write an ESP (*it's just ignored & its only a small amount of wasted disk space*) so it'll depend on what ISO you installed with, PLUS what options were used by install as to whether or not you can just move your drive across (*on all ISOs you can force creation of ESP or prevent ESP from being written desktop ISOs anyway*).  You gave no such details.

Comment: @guiverc it's been quite a few years since I installed 18.04 on that SSD, so don't remember if the 18.04 ISO mentioned anything about ESP.

Comment: If you don't have the ESP (EFI System Partition) the drive will not boot on an uEFI/Secure-uEFI machine; as the ESP replaced the MBR used by legacy 1982 & later BIOS machines.  You can usually spot it (ESP partitions are small & mandated to be a specific formats to reliably work); or you can watch for clues on certain commands, eg. a `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` on my existing box tells me "*Installing for x86_64-efi platform.*" which tells me I'll have an ESP (the box actually has two; untouched & unused windows ESP that I considered too small; plus one used by both my Ubuntu installs).

Comment: @guiverc (My system is dead so I can't check.)  Does this mean I'll have to reinstall (presumably using 22.04) once I'm on the new system?

Comment: I was just trying to give clues on what to look for, ie. `blkid` for mine shows `/dev/sda1: UUID="86FB-0B32" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="174dc261-8988-4f64-b680-9cbc94e6d876"` being the ESP for the windows 11 I don't use, and `/dev/sda5: LABEL_FATBOOT="UBU_ESP" LABEL="UBU_ESP" UUID="FE36-F64F" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="f6a93984-cd3b-6c41-bbd2-5333f364f592"` being ESP I created during install of the two Ubuntu OSes on this box (last month when my old BIOS box died; I didn't try & re-use drive; just copied the data I wanted from backups)

Comment: @guiverc thanks.

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop ISOS for recent releases create an ESP even if not required (*though using some install options can cause it not to be created*), but in comparison Lubuntu ISOs from 18.10 & later would not (*if using BIOS*), but I can't recall what was created on 18.04 as that was too long ago for me to be reliable.  I'd look and see

Comment: @guiverc is the ESP partition "large" (like 512MB), and visible by gparted?  If so, then I don't have it on my system.

Comment: My windows ESP was 100MB (*what I considered too small for 3x OSes; I'll only wipe the windows 11 when I need the disk space then have 2xUbuntu*) thus I created a larger 512MB ESP. ESP size is often 100MB or 300MB with 512MB on the larger end (*common for more recent installs; for smaller is more common for older installs or single-OS*)

Comment: @guiverc however large it "should" be, it's large enough that I'd notice it in the partition table...  This answers my question.

Comment: @guiverc the SSD from my old BIOS mobo booted right up in my UEFI mobo.

Comment: Thanks for letting me/us know; Ubuntu ISOs for some time, have by default created an ESP so that will occur; however not all do (eg. *Lubuntu in my example that creates it only if booted using uEFI mode prior to install; I'm using Lubuntu as example here only*)..   Installation impacts this to a large extent (ie. *which includes ISO used & options used during install*).  If your problem is solved; you can write up your own answer; feel free to include any details I/others provided too esp. if helpful (*ref. me/others too if you wish*) but it can be largely based on what you did & your solution

Comment: @guiverc I don't see anything that looks like an ESP on my boot disk.  The only partitions are fat32 `/dos`, ext4 `/`, linux-swap and xs `/home`.

Comment: The ESP is the EFI System Partition; usually small vFAT partition and is necessary to boot on a uEFI system if its not in legacy/CSM mode  (when in *legacy* mode it'll boot the same as any BIOS computer from 1982 & later as per standard if x86/IBM PC compatible architecture).  The ESP is the *newer* standard that replaced the original IBM standard; instead of the reserved MBR on the disk that is booted; the ESP partition is read & used allowing for more than 512 bytes of code to be included...

Comment: @guiverc "if its not in legacy/CSM mode".  Ah... I bet my mobo is configured by default to be in legacy mode.